# ActionBar Menu Theme Issue in Latest Android L release

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop

In the latest Android L emulator released today (17th october 2014) I'm getting strange issue:
the action bar menu font theme seems ignored and the color of the font is black despite I have

```
`<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">`
```

In the previous release, Android L Preview API level 20, the font color of the action bar menu was correctly rendered with a white color, and also in all previous versions

[image]

I have also tried to remove all theme customizations leaving only this

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/White</item>   

    </style>

</resources>
```

With no result.

Is this a bug of the Android Lollipop emulator or should I change something?
Seems pretty strange that everything works fine with Android L preview and with the official release get this issue.
Any suggestion?

*Additional Information:*

-The emulator configuration is Android Atom x86_64 API Level 21 (tested also on 32 bit version with the same result), *use host GPU* enabled... tested also with ARM v7 CPU *no use host GPU* option and get the same result

-The app target set in App Manifest is Android API Level 17, the minimum SDK is API level 14

-The project use the Android Support library v4 released today (17-10-2014)

Comment: I'd try a non-64-bit emulator and see what happens.

Comment: I have tried now on 32bit version but same result.

Comment: [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ActionBarDemoNative) shows up with a normal-looking action bar on a 5.0 x86 emulator. It uses `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` directly, not through a custom theme inheriting from it. You might try temporarily replacing your theme with `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` and see if it works. If it does, then it is something in your custom theme.

Comment: @CommonsWare I get the issue also using the default theme, With default theme the menu background appears in light grey color with black font despite I have specifically choosen Holo.Light.DarkAction Bar. See the update

Comment: any updates from this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Create a `style.xml` in a resource folder named `values-v21`

[image]

2) Now you have 2 options
   a) Copy your actual style configuration in the new `style.xml` created, replacing the keyword
      ***Holo*** with the keyword ***Material***; 
   b) define new material style from scratch;
      this is needed to use the new `Material` theme on Android L

In this way you will fix all compatibility problems caused by *Holo* theme on the new Android L